# Vuetify table - custom css isn't applied to first row after page reload

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Table:

```
<v-card :dark="true">
      <v-card-title>
        <v-btn color="indigo" dark @click="initialize"><v-icon dark>refresh</v-icon></v-btn>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-text-field append-icon="search" label="Search" single-line hide-details></v-text-field>
      </v-card-title>
      <v-data-table :dark="true" :headers="headers" :items="expenses" hide-actions class="elevation-1">
        <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
          <tr>
            <th v-for="header in props.headers">{{header.text}}</th>
          </tr>
        </template>
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
          <tr v-bind:class="getClass(props.item)">
            <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.year }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.month }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.day }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.description }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.value }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.category }}</td>
            <td class="text-xs-center">{{ props.item.details }}</td>
            <td class="justify-center layout px-0">
              <v-btn icon class="mx-0" @click="deleteItem(props.item)">
                <v-icon color="pink">delete</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
        <template slot="no-data">
          <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize">Reset</v-btn>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </v-card>
```

Css before page reload, after the code is edited in Webstorm and automatically compiled:

[image: before]

And after the reload:

[image: after]

And if I just remove the first row, the same happens no matter which one is first.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same problem.

They problem here is that You override the items slot including `<tr>` tag. Without that everything will work fine. But for me, that was not a solution so if You want to override the `<tr>` tag also, **add :key to it, like this: `<tr :key="props.index">`**.
Take a look at source of v-data-table [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/mixins/body.js#L49).
To be honest, i don't know why it make that big difference but in my case that resolved the problem (i suspect that it is connected with vue list rendering).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Turns out I upvoted this answer almost a year ago. And it's still a problem in Vuetify 2. Funny how I faced the exact same issue a year apart without realizing.